# Why doesn't ImageIO preserve JPEG data when repeatedly loading and saving?

Tags: kotlin, jpeg, javax.imageio

Originally I wanted to try whether it is possible to reconstruct redacted data from a JPEG image, given that it is a lossy image format and the pixel values spread into the neighbor pixels.

To test whether saving and loading JPEG images is reliable, I wrote the following program that repeatedly saves and loads a JPEG image until it reaches an image that has been seen before. Here is the code:

```
package de.roland_illig.jpg

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.security.MessageDigest
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    fun loadJpeg(bytes: ByteArray) =
            ImageIO.read(ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))

    fun saveJpeg(img: BufferedImage) =
            ByteArrayOutputStream().apply { use { ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", it) } }.toByteArray()

    fun hash(bytes: ByteArray) =
            DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(bytes))

    var bytes = saveJpeg(ImageIO.read(File("000-original.png")))

    val log = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
    for (n in 1..Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        Files.write(Paths.get("%03d.jpg".format(n)), bytes)
        val hash = hash(bytes)
        val prev = log.put(hash, n)
        if (prev != null) {
            println("After $n steps, the image is the same as after $prev steps.")
            break
        }

        bytes = saveJpeg(loadJpeg(bytes))
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that for a random screenshot, it takes between 20 and 49 steps until the image becomes stable. Ideally I would have expected always 2 steps.

Even though JPEG is a lossy format, after saving it and loading it again, each pixel has a certain value. Whatever compression is used, when compressing the same data again, I had expected that the compressed data is also the same:

```
val original = loadPng()              // Exact in-memory image
val jpeg0Bytes = saveJpeg(original)   // Saved with JPEG artifacts
val jpeg = loadJpeg(jpeg0Bytes)       // Lossy, loaded again
val jpeg1Bytes = saveJpeg(jpeg)       // Should be the same as jpeg0Bytes
```

I only tried with the default quality settings of Java's ImageIO, but a manual experiment with GIMP showed similar results.

Now I wonder why the image libraries don't implement the JPEG compression so that the above program would stop after 2 steps. Is it really so hard to eliminate rounding errors or whatever else might create these artifacts?

Comment: Jpeg encoders and decoders are a compromise of visual fidelity, processing speed, file size, and probably other parameters. Not everyone uses the same balance. Have you tried writing your own jpeg encoder and decoder to see if you can get the result you would ilke? Does it then work for a different image?

Comment: Do you have an example of a stable image that you could show us?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, I didn't write my own JPEG encoder, and I don't think I ever will. As for an example image, you can easily generate one using the code I posted. Just save an arbitrary PNG file as `000-original.png` and run the code.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841834/is-re-encoding-jpeg-images-an-idempotent-operation